# Whole Slide Image in AI

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-selection, semantic-segmentation

I have whole slide images of Acute Ischemic Stroke (Cardio Embolic and Large Artery Atherosclerosis ) and I need to classify them to CE or LAA .I have used deep zoom generator and created tiles of WSI but I don't know how to benefit from them [It has fibrin and red blood cells components but I don't know how they look to segment them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUjDI.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xk3p.png)

If someone knows how to use tiles of image and how I can classify the clot from (all the tiles )